# TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'> for date function

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Objective: Calculate days between both days

```
Value          int64
Date           int64
Month          int64
Year           int64
Day            int64
LocationID     int32
CategoryID     int32
```

The l_date could not run

```
def my_function(train):
    train['f_date'] = date(2016, 1, 1)
    train['l_date'] = date(train['Year'], train['Month'], train['Date'])
    train['date_block'] = train['l_date']-train['f_date']
    return train
```

Update**(Date is 1-31 fyi)

```
def my_function(train):
    train['f_date'] = date(2016,1,1)
    train["l_date"] = pd.to_datetime({'year': train['Year'],
                   'month': train['Month'],
                   'day': train['Date']})
    train['date_block'] = train['l_date']-train['f_date']
    return train
```

New Error
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'datetime.date'

Comment: Do you import datetime from datetime in your script ?

Comment: `train['Year']` will return a series not an `int` and same for `train['Month']` and  `train['Date']`

Comment: I have alrd included from datetime import date

Comment: how should i correct this line for returning a series not an int

train['l_date'] = date(train['Year'], train['Month'], train['Date'])

Answer (score 0):

You should use pd.to_datetime.
The line

```
train['l_date'] = date(train['Year'], train['Month'], train['Date'])
```

should be corrected as

```
train["l_date"] = pd.to_datetime(train[['Year','Month','Day']])
```

I think that also you type wrong day with date.

The problem is that datetime.date wants integers, but df["colname"] returns a Series. pd.to_datetime can be used to work with Series and DataFrames.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'datetime.date'

Comment: Error happen at
`train['date_block'] = train['l_date']-train['f_date']`

is it due to
`train['f_date'] = date(2016,1,1)`

Comment: You could convert train['f_date'] as follow: `train['date_block'] = train['l_date']-pd.to_datetime(train['f_date'])`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def my_function(train):
    train['f_date'] = datetime(2016, 1, 1)
    train["l_date"] = pd.to_datetime({'year': train['Year'],
                   'month': train['Month'],
                   'day': train['Date']})
    train['date_block'] = train['l_date']-train['f_date']
    return train
```